# How can I calculate the grouped averages and maximums per day for a range of dates and times?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a CSV dump describing the utilisation percentage of some servers in my organisation, covering data samples from several times per day. Each server belongs to a group. **For each group, I have to calculate the maximum and average utilisation per day. How can I do this in Excel 2010?** (I have no access to add-ins or ability to install extra software)

## The data I have

I have a CSV file I can modify freely: save in an Excel format, add/change rows/columns, set ranges, etc. It has the following format:

- The first row is a series of date-times: `28/08/2014 18:00`, `29/08/2014 00:00`, `29/08/2014 6:00`, and so on. (That's Australian date formats.)
- Each row beneath is the name of a server and its group, followed by its performance percentage for each date-time.

As a visual example (mocked up in Excel 2013, though I still have to do my work in Excel 2010):

> [image]

... except for a full 7-day week, with 3-4 samples per day.

## What I need to produce (somehow)

From that, as stated, I need to get the average and maximum **per day, per group.** So from the above graph, I'd be able to produce the below. I've tried to make sure the numbers are actually accurate.

> [image]

The average for Beta on 29/08/2014 is calculated here with `=AVERAGE(D4:F6)`. That's not completely accurate for the entire day, but **this doesn't have to be perfect.** Thanks to the broad samples, it's not going to be too accurate anyway. It just needs to be indicative.

From that, finally, I'll produce this graph for a report (again from Excel 2013):

> [image]

*Phew.* That's all the detail.

**How on earth can I do this!?**

There seem to be a variety of different ways to calculate various date ranges in Excel, but the one I've found that's the closest to my actual data is [Calculating Averages by Date from ExcelTips](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010319_Calculating_Averages_by_Date.html), which despite being written for Excel 2010, doesn't seem to work. (Instead of giving me averages for various days, it tends to just give me a lot of 0's and then particular non-average values from particular days.)

Comment: I know its not an exact answer to your question, so I'll add it as a comment: please do consider to use a tool on your servers that is specifically made for this, like [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/). Other alternatives can be found [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers). That saves a lot of trouble and gives you a lot of extra features. And it's free (as in free speech, not as in free beer ;-)

Comment: I would happily use one of those, and thanks for the recommendation - unfortunately I have no control over the servers here, and this CSV is about the best I can get.